# Todos os dados de uma linha no dataframe estão indo para a primeira coluna utilizando Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou lendo um arquivo csv com pandas em um dataframe, acontece que na **linha 10**, todos os dados estão indo para a primeira coluna, desta forma:

[image: Dataframe obtido]

Como posso resolver esse problema e separar corretamente? Preciso que só o primeiro número fique na coluna ID.

A linha no arquivo csv está dessa forma:

9009101002,"Smartphone Apple iPhone XS 256GB 4G Tela 5,8"""" Câmera 12MP Frontal 7MP iOS 12 Dourado",   32 934,102,401

E foi gerada automaticamente pelo sistema.

[image: Arquivo CSV]

Para ler o arquivo, uso a seguinte linha de código:

`df = pd.read_csv("prods_tab.csv", encoding='latin-1', sep=',')`

**Obs.: Ao abrir o arquivo em bloco de notas, o mesmo se apresenta da seguinte maneira:**

```
ID. Forn.,Prod. DESC.,SKU.,GRP. MERC. 3,COD. MARC.
,,,,
302100012,GELADEIRA FROST FREE INVERTER IB53X ELECTROLUX 454 LITROS INOX,100312-,996,302
302100012,GELADEIRA FROST FREE DB84 ELECTROLUX 598 LITROS BRANCO,89 721 ?,,
302100012,Frigobar Electrolux RE80 79 Litros Classe A 110V Branco,?1920-- 63,996,302
,,,,
ID. Forn.,Prod. DESC.,SKU.,GRP. MERC. 3,COD. MARC.
302100012,Geladeira Electrolux SS72X Side by Side Frost Free 504 Litros 2 Portas Classe A 127V Inox,18228 5,996,302
,,,,
ID. Forn.,Prod. DESC.,SKU.,GRP. MERC. 3,COD. MARC.
,,,,
"9009101002,""Smartphone Apple iPhone XS 256GB 4G Tela 5,8"""""""" Câmera 12MP Frontal 7MP iOS 12 Dourado"",   32 934,102,401"
9030121093,SMARTPHONE SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE 8 N950F 64GB 2CHIPS PRETO,4??349 5,102,607
320621093,BONECA MULTIKIDS BUSH BABY WORLD SHIMMIES BR106,4342I,766,481
320621093,Brinquedo Kit de Voley Disney Princesas Líder 759 ,3 1---24-,766,481
9030121093,SMARTPHONE SAMSUNG GALAXY A8+ A730 64GB 2CHIPS DOURADO,  1 92501 ,,607
,,,,
```

**Obs2.: Eu já tratei as outras linhas, só está faltando essa.**

Comment: tem uma virgula ali não tem? na linha 10, foi colocada por você ou gerada pelo sistema?

Comment: Como está estruturado o seu csv (principalmente a linha 10)? Por favor edite a pergunta e adicione esta informação.

Comment: Reforçando o que falou o @AlexCiuffa, adicione as 10-12 primeiras linhas do seu csv à pergunta.

Comment: @RafaelRotiroti foi gerada pelo sistema.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa editado, adiconei a informação.

Comment: @Sidon editado.

Comment: Pode colocar a linha em que você usa o read_csv() ?, fica melhor pra ver os parâmetros passados.

Comment: @Rafael pronto. :)

Comment: Com os dados que você passou não foi possível replicar o erro aqui. Montei um arquivo `prods_tab.csv` com o cabeçalho e a linha passada, chamei `df = pd.read_csv("prods_tab.csv", encoding='latin-1', sep=',')` e funcionou normalmente. Tente disponibilizar o arquivo com um recorte dos dados para que seja possível replicar esse erro. Deve ter alguma coisa a mais nesse CSV que está escapando aos olhos.

Comment: Fiz testes aqui também, o problema realmente é o CSV, não há um padrão de separação, horas há TAB ou alguma virgula, o ideal é utilizar só um fiz essa adaptação para TAB's e funcionou, esse CSV é privado ou alguma base de testes só?

Comment: @Rafael ele faz parte de um teste que estou fazendo para trainee em uma empresa. Poderia me auxiliar melhor como faço a adaptação para TAB's?

Comment: Eu só substitui as separações por TAB's mas se o seu dataset é muito grande não compensa leva muito tempo se houver muitas separações diferentes. Mas de qualquer forma a primeira imagem com os dados em colunas é referente ao dataset ou só uma representação do sistema, pergunto pois na planilha excel tem uma representação diferente.

Comment: @Rafael então, o dataset é pequeno. Retirei a primeira imagem e coloquei como está aparecendo o dataframe, aquela imagem estava confusa, mas era uma cópia do dataframe apresentado no jupyter notebook. Enfim, não sei como resolver isso e preciso entregar :(

Comment: Assim tu ta usando excel, vai no local desse arquivo, clica com botão direito nele, e clica em editar, vai abrir no bloco de notas, ai tu vai ver como os dados realmente estão, copia esse mesmo trecho do teu exemplo acima e coloca na pergunta.

Comment: @Rafael Fiz isso e percebi que a linha que está com problema tá entre aspas... Será que tem algo a ver?

Comment: Sim, sempre que tu for resolver um problema de analise de dados abre eles com o bloco de notas, já posto uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas é uma baita ferramenta, mas as vezes os dados não estão bem "normalizados", era teu caso, não entendi o porque daquelas aspas mas eram um dos problemas, tu tinha teu cabeçalho três vezes no texto tenta deixar sempre no começo e uma vez só, alias o cabeçalho tu pode deixar entre aspas cada coluna, mas sempre cuida a separação, até um espaço em branco já é um motivo. A seguir o read_csv que usei.

```
df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', engine = 'python', error_bad_lines = False, sep = ',')
```

E o dataset:

```
"ID. Forn.","Prod. DESC.","SKU.","GRP. MERC. 3","COD. MARC."
302100012,GELADEIRA FROST FREE INVERTER IB53X ELECTROLUX 454 LITROS INOX,100312-,996,302
302100012,GELADEIRA FROST FREE DB84 ELECTROLUX 598 LITROS BRANCO,89 721 ?,,
302100012,Frigobar Electrolux RE80 79 Litros Classe A 110V Branco,?1920-- 63,996,302
302100012,Geladeira Electrolux SS72X Side by Side Frost Free 504 Litros 2 Portas Classe A 127V Inox,18228 5,996,302
9009101002, smartphone Apple iPhone XS 256GB 4G Tela 5,8 Câmera 12MP Frontal 7MP iOS 12 Dourado,   32 934,102,401
9030121093,SMARTPHONE SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE 8 N950F 64GB 2CHIPS PRETO,4??349 5,102,607
320621093,BONECA MULTIKIDS BUSH BABY WORLD SHIMMIES BR106,4342I,766,481
320621093,Brinquedo Kit de Voley Disney Princesas Líder 759 ,3 1---24-,766,481
9030121093,SMARTPHONE SAMSUNG GALAXY A8+ A730 64GB 2CHIPS DOURADO,  1 92501 ,,607
```

Comment: Rafael, realmente... Aquelas aspas eram o problema então, como eu recebi o dataset para resolver, não me atentei a isso.

Muito obrigado!!